# Simple question about Scala generics

Tags: generics, scala

What is the difference between `X[Any]` and `X[_]` ?

Let's consider, for example, two functions below:

```
def foo(x:X[_]){}
```

```
def foo(x:X[Any]){}
```

What is exactly the difference between these declarations above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is an existential type, and the second is a normal type. The first syntax actually means this:

```
def foo(x:X[t] forSome { type t }){}
```

What this means is that `x` is of type `X[t]`, where `t` can be any unspecified `type t`.

Intuitively, `X[_]` means the type parameter of `X` is irrelevant, whereas `X[Any]` says it must be `Any`.

Comment: OK, then what's the difference between  `def foo(x:X[_]){}` and `def foo[Y <: Any](a : X[Y])` ?

Comment: @Malvolio `Y` will be known. In fact, I think it _must_ be known -- that if you have an existential type, you can't then pass it to something expecting `Y <: Any`.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is in insignificant

```
scala> class X[T]   
defined class X

scala> def type_of[T](x: X[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = m.toString
type_of: [T](x: X[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T])java.lang.String

scala> val x1: X[Any] = new X
x1: X[Any] = X@1a40cfc

scala> val x2: X[_] = new X  
x2: X[_] = X@29d838

scala> type_of(x1)
res10: java.lang.String = Any

scala> type_of(x2)
res11: java.lang.String = _ <: Any
```

I can not name a situation, when you can use Any but can not use _ and vice verse.

Comment: You're making the assumption that X is covariant. If X is invariant, then it may be necessary to use the existential form if you need to use it as though it were covariant.

Comment: Well, try to call a method expecting an Array[Any] with an Array[Int]. It will not work. On the other hand, calling a method expecting an Array[_] with Array[Int] or Array[whatever you like] is perfectly ok. As Kris writes, variance is key. So Daniel's answer is the correct one.

Comment: Who on earth has upvoted this? It is a terrible and wrong answer.